# Regular Expression for finding numbers of this format num:num:num:num

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I know this is basic, but I am not sure, where I am going wrong and never wrote regular expression before..

I need to grep some output out of a command

```
cmd | grep '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

I need to grep some information of the format

```
dummy dummy 4:9:93:022 dummy
```

How do I do that? Please let me know where I am going wrong.....

Output will be of format

```
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=2 status=active
|- 6:0:0:136 sdip 135:144 active ready running
`- 5:0:0:136 sdle 67:448  active ready running
```

I need to remove it only based on that 6:0:0:136....

Comment: Why are there forward slashes?

Comment: I removed it same result... I will edit that,....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus modifier is part of the "extended regular expression" syntax. This:

```
a+
```

means "one or more 'a' characters" and is shorthand for this basic expression:

```
aa*
```

Traditionally `grep` supports basic regular expressions and `egrep` supports the extended syntax. So do this:

```
cmd | egrep '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

or this (which is the same thing):

```
cmd | grep -E '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 3):

You either need to escape each `+` with a backslash, or use the extended regex option (`-E` or `--extended-regexp`):

```
cmd | grep '[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+'
```

or:

```
cmd | grep -E '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
>          In  basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
cmd | grep -E '([0-9]+:){3}[0-9]+'
```